# question on multiple integrals, volume

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

compute volume of a figure bounded by $z=2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=0$.
I don't know how to do this, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "boundary" curve is defined by: $2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0$, or $x^2+y^2 = 4=2^2$ which is a circle centered at $(0,0)$, and having radius $r = 2$. Cylindrical coordinates seems to be the natural choice here. So:

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^2 \int_{0}^{2-r} rdzdrd\theta$

Comment: aren't the differentials: $drd \theta dz$?

Comment: No, its $rdrd\theta dz$

Comment: I got this finally.